# searching array of words faster

Tags: mysql, database, search, words

i want to look how much an array comes in a database. Its pretty slow and i want to know if there's a way of searching like multiple words or an whole array without a for loop.. i'm struggeling for a while now.

here's my code

```
   $dateBegin = "2010-12-07 15:54:24.0";
$dateEnd = "2010-12-30 18:19:52.0";
$textPerson = " text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text  text text "; 



$textPersonExplode = explode(" ", $textPerson );



$db = dbConnect();
for ( $counter = 0;$counter <= sizeof($textPersonExplode)-1 ; $counter++) {


$query = "SELECT count(word) FROM `news_google_split`  WHERE `word` LIKE '$textPersonExplode[$counter]'   AND  `date` >= '$dateBegin' AND `date` <= '$dateEnd'"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());



while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
 $word[] = $textPersonExplode[$counter];
 $count[] = $row[0];



}
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
}
```

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the for loop if you use MATCH..AGAINST pair in your query. i.e:

```
    $query = "SELECT count(word) FROM `news_google_split`  WHERE MATCH(`word`) AGAINST   
('$textPerson')   AND  `date` >= '$dateBegin' AND `date` <= '$dateEnd'";
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but it's still a littlebit slow. But it will be better than waiting 3 minutes.

Comment: Did you define the fulltext index?

Comment: Could i get the information of each word i send in seperatly? Now it's the total of the input.

Comment: Yes, i did define the full-text index. It's an index of more than 2 milion words.

Comment: Try this: "SELECT `word`, count(word) FROM `news_google_split`  WHERE MATCH(`word`) AGAINST ('$textPerson')   AND  `date` >= '$dateBegin' AND `date` <= '$dateEnd' GROUP BY `word`"

Answer (score 0):

Check out [full text indexing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: i've allready looked into that, but i couldn't get it working right. How must i make the query then?

Comment: Use the MATCH...AGAINST syntax.  `SELECT headline, story FROM news
WHERE MATCH (headline,story) AGAINST ('Hurricane');`  Also note that the table has to be MyISAM.

Answer (score 0):

We send a comma seperated list in Db, then converted that list into a table, then we used that table in our queries in the form of joins.

However you need to make sure how much data you can pass in as the input of the query or stored procedure.